# How to add fragments to Navigation Drawer template in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio

I've searched all over Google trying to find the answer but haven't been able to find an answer. I'm using the "Create Navigation Drawer Activity" template in Android Studio. How do I add my fragments to the Navigation Drawer?

Here's where I assume I add the fragments:

```
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camara) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Based on tutorials I've seen, I've tried adding the following in the if statements with no success:

```
    fragment = new ItemFragment();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Switch between Fragments with onNavigationItemSelected in new Navigation Drawer Activity template (Android Studio 1.4 onward)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32944798/switch-between-fragments-with-onnavigationitemselected-in-new-navigation-drawer)

Comment: @user3424545 this isn't a duplicate. I didn't see that one. I gave up on this question though. Didn't solve my problem. If I run into this issue again, I'll be sure to check that link. Thanks