# Fragment type error in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I was following the directions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32944798/switch-between-fragments-with-onnavigationitemselected-in-new-navigation-drawer) post on how to switch between fragments within the Sliding Drawer Activity in Android Studio and I'm positive I've followed the steps correctly as displayed. However, at the end of my `displayView` method the compiler is complaining that a fragment object I am referencing is incompatible with the method I'm passing it into. The method requires `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` whereas the fragment object I am using is (apparently) `android.app.Fragment`. Although I know this to be false as well because if I explicitly define my `Fragment` like so :

`android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment = null;`

the original error is fixed but rest of the references throughout the `switch` `case` begin complaining for the *same reason*:

```
Error:(135, 44) error: incompatible types: android.app.Fragment cannot be converted to android.support.v4.app.Fragment
```

I have absolutely no idea what could be causing such an issue, however I'm no expert at using the Android SDK; there could very well be something I'm just missing. All feedback and assistance is appreciated; I'm on a time crunch for this app and need to finish it very soon. Thank you!

Below is the `displayView` method:

```
public void displayView(int viewId) {

    Fragment fragment = null;
    String title = getString(R.string.app_name);

    switch (viewId) {
        case R.id.nav_newsfeed:
            fragment = new Feed_Fragment();
            title  = "News Feed";

            break;
        case R.id.nav_camera:
            fragment = new Post_Fragment();
            title = "Post a Picture";
            break;
        case R.id.nav_gallery:
            fragment = new Gallery_Fragment();
            title = "Your Posts";

            break;
        case R.id.nav_send:
            fragment = new Message_Fragment();
            title = "Direct Message";

            break;
        /*case R.id.nav_manage:
            //fragment = new Settings_Fragment();
            title = "Account Settings";

            break;
        case R.id.nav_share:
            //fragment = new Share_Fragment();
            title = "Share";

            break;*/

    }
    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment); //2nd parameter causes issue
        ft.commit();
    }

    // set the toolbar title
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

}
```

Comment: Just change your Fragments class to extend from `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` instead of `android.app.Fragment`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Error:(135, 44) error: incompatible types: android.app.Fragment cannot
>   be converted to android.support.v4.app.Fragment

You are using `getSupportFragmentManager`

Just **import** `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` instead of `instead of android.app.Fragment`

You should be doing

```
import android.app.Fragment
```

Change that to

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
```

Then **Clean-Rebuild** your Project .

Try this .Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! My problem was that I forgot to import the proper `Fragment` class in the fragments I was using within my `switch` `case`. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

welcome to `polymorphism` through `Inheritance`

try to understand although you are trying to change `Fragment` which is here `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` your reference variable should also be from that class, right now your reference variable fragment is of type is here  `android.app.Fragment`. as your method does not get the reference variable of type `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`, it shows you the error

as there is conflict in it you have to change the  `Fragment fragment` to get the the class from here `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`

When your are dealing with fragments, make sure your from where are you referencing them from. As this is the common problem. Many confuse between `android.app.Fragment` to `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`

what you need is `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` for the reference variable for type `Fragment`

Answer (score 1):

Your Fragments (Feed_Fragment, Post_Fragment, Gallery_Fragment, Message_Fragment...) must extend from `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` instead of `android.app.Fragment`.

Also in your activity import `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` instead of `android.app.Fragment`.