# Switching Fragments in navigation drawer using onNavigationItemSelected()

Tags: android, android-fragments

So I have gone through many answers on StackOverFlow but could not get this working. I want to switch fragments on navigation drawer item click. I am using the default navigation drawer in Android Studio 1.5.

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32944798/switch-between-fragments-with-onnavigationitemselected-in-new-navigation-drawer) answer, i have made sure that i have all my fragments created. The problem is whenever i click on any menu item the app stops working. Here's what I have till now.

MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        displayView(R.id.twitter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        displayView(item.getItemId());
        return true;
    }

    public void displayView(int viewId) {

        Fragment fragment = null;
        String title = getString(R.string.app_name);

        switch (viewId) {
            case R.id.facebook:
                fragment = new FacebookFragment();
                title = "Facebook";
                break;
            case R.id.twitter:
                fragment = new TwitterFragment();
                title = "Twitter";
                break;
            case R.id.googleplus:
                fragment = new GooglePlusFragment();
                title = "Google Plus";
                break;
            case R.id.settings:
                fragment = new SettingsFragment();
                title = "Settings";
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
            ft.commit();
        }

        // set the toolbar title
        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

    }
}
```

FacebookFragment.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link FacebookFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link FacebookFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class FacebookFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public FacebookFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment FacebookFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static FacebookFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        FacebookFragment fragment = new FacebookFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_facebook, container, false);
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p/>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

I have added FrameLayout to content_main.xml file as it was suggested in the question i referred to. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any error after clicking on NavigationDrawer item?

Comment: I don't know what the error is, but as soon as i click on menu item the application stops working error comes up.

Comment: @Guilherme P in logcat i see this error java.lang.RuntimeException: com.internetwarz.sploon.MainActivity@3caae0bc must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener.

I tried commenting the code and found out that the main error is caused due to the lines where i call the fragment. i.e fragment = new FacebookFragment();

Comment: Exception is thrown from onAttach() method in fragment. Comment it for testing your error.

Comment: Yes, i commented it and the application no longer crashes. Can you explain to me why this happened? Any link or guide would be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By your logcat, error is:

`com.internetwarz.sploon.MainActivity@3caae0bc must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener`

I think the error happened because your parent activity (MainActivity.java) did not implement this method: `OnFragmentInteractionListener`

You can see by the comments:

```
/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 */
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
```

So, the solution would be:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,
               FacebookFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

    ....

    // Add the method below to MainActivity.java
    private void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {
        // Do something or just return
        Toast.makeText(this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, what you suggested did work. I just have one more question. Do I have to implement each and every fragment separately in MainActivity.java ?

Comment: I did not understand the question. Your code seems normal... Just FacebookFragment which request to implement that additional method (I'm not sure the propose of that method)