# Action Bar Title Not Updating onNavigationItemSelected

Tags: java, android

I am trying to learn using Android Studio's built in templates. I have the Navigation Drawer variant selected currently, and I am trying to use the `onNavigationItemSelected` method determine the `supportActionBar` title using the following code:

```
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
         // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(item.getTitle()); ...
```

The issue is that once I start loading fragments, the title isn't updating whenever I select a new navigation item. I have checked to see if the method is firing every time an item in the drawer is selected, and it does, so I can't tell why this isn't updating.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you need to set in fragment not here!

Comment: I've tried that by the `((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Title Here");` and it is not working still
`

Comment: Check it might helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32944798/switch-between-fragments-with-onnavigationitemselected-in-new-navigation-drawer