# How to open Activity from Android's built-in navigation drawer

Tags: java, android, android-activity, navigation-drawer

I have seen numerous people having the same problem, but when I try their solutions, it still doesn't work opening an activity from the navigation drawer.

The code for my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

//region Properties
private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
ImageButton settings_btn;
//endregion

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    ProductDatabase productDb = new ProductDatabase();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    settings_btn = findViewById(R.id.btn_settings);
    settings_btn.setOnClickListener(v ->
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class)));

    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(view -> Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
            .setAction("Action", null).show());

    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_login, R.id.nav_treatments, R.id.nav_product, R.id.nav_about, R.id.nav_contactUs)
            .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
            .build();
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
}

@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
            || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_booking) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, BookingActivity.class));
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_home) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_product) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_treatments) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_about) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_contactUs) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
    }
}
```

When I run this code and click on the "Booking" tab. Nothing happens. Booking was a Fragment before, but now I just wanted it to open an Activity while all the other options opens fragments.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure that your activity call button has id nav_booking, have you tested your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
```

I did not see this line of code in your code. Apparently you didn’t set a listener

Comment: If my answer helped you, mark it as correct by clicking on the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Comment: Can't do it before 5 minutes has passed

Comment: I faced another problem when adding ur code. After adding the code, all the other options didn't work. So only the BookingActivity works and not the other fragments

Comment: So in my onNavigationItemSelected, I need to start the other fragments when getting their id. But how do I start a fragment from an activity?

Comment: I think that this is due to the fact that now you have to manage the inclusion of fragments yourself. Now I will find information

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32944798/switch-between-fragments-with-onnavigationitemselected-in-new-navigation-drawer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211713/discussion-between-dannytraan-and-destroyer).